# Clipless Pedal - Flat Attachment

Tags: pedals, clipless

I have some clipless pedals I salvaged (part of a crankset) and installed on my bike. It's the winter right now and I don't really want to be clipped in. I don't want to replace the pedals either - mainly because one of them is stuck :)

Do they make some kind of clip on platform for clipless pedals that I can install in lieu of the proper shoes?

Comment: There are a few platform attachments available, but I can't find any good links at present.  Apparently Crank Brothers makes one for their pedals, and I recall seeing at least one style available for SPD.  I thought the links were in a post here somewhere, but can't find it.

Comment: (Do remember that the left side pedal unscrews "backwards" -- clockwise.)

Comment: Your local bike shop can help you remove your pedals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've used platforms similar to this one:

> http://www.universalcycles.com/shopping/product_details.php?id=22313&category=1669

But after looking around a bit, I saw this product, which looks a little more rugged since you screw your actual cleats into the platform to clip it in rather than relaying on the molded plastic of the platform:

> http://problemsolversbike.com/products/deckster_clipless_pedal_adapter

But have found that these platforms are really a temporary solution meant to let you ride to the corner store, not meant for long term use. Since the platforms clip in like a shoe, they can clip out like a shoe and they float around a bit, so don't feel super stable. Also, they make the pedal top heavy, so the platform always ends up on the bottom and you have to flip it around (gently) so you can get your foot on it - if you hit it too hard when you're trying to flip it, it's easy to knock the platform off.

Your best bet is to try to get the stuck pedal off and put on the pedals you want to use. Here are some tips on removing a stuck pedal: [Removing a stuck pedal](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/removing-a-stuck-pedal)

I've never had to resort to using heat, but I've been told that it's a sure fire way to loosen a stuck pedal because aluminum expands more than steel when heated.

But first, as mentioned above, make sure you're unscrewing in the correct direction, and use a good quality pedal wrench.

Comment: Also, once you get the pedal removed you can look into getting clipless pedals with plaforms build in. There's a few different models available.