# Schwinn AC Plus Performance Carbon Blue spin bike pedal removal

Tags: pedals

What tools do I need to remove pedal from crank arm?

I assembled pedals to wrong pedals to the crank arm. Right pedal to left and left pedal to right.

I can't remove it. What size crank puller do I need to remove?

Comment: Do you really mean you need to remove pedals from the crank arms, or the crank arms from the axle? Right hand pedals have a right hand thread and left hand pedals have a left hand thread so you can't install them them in the wrong crank arm. A crank puller is for removing crank arms from the axle.

Comment: If you installed the pedals on the wrong sides you'll probably need to replace the crank arms, but it's worth a try to just unscrew the pedals and put then in correctly.

Comment: Can't find a close enough view to see what sort of crank puller might be needed, if it comes to that.  It looks fairly standard, but hard to say for sure.

Comment: @ArgentiApparatus some people _can_ install the pedals in the wrong crank arm!

Comment: Related   https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/questions/8512/removing-a-stuck-pedal   However your error means that everything is reversed when compared to these photos.

Answer (score 1):

To remove a pedal from a crank arm is merely a matter of unthreading it.

Most pedals use a pair of flat surfaces just outboard of the crank.  A normal adjustable spanner may fit, but the proper tool is a thinner pedal spanner with a width of 15mm

[image: Park tool]

Pedals may also have a hex driver socket on the inboard end of the shaft.  This might be a 6mm, 8mm, or 10mm hole and is driven with an allen key.

[image: Park tool]

Some pedals have both flats and hex hole.

---

The "Crank Puller" is the **wrong tool** for the job.  A puller works to remove the crank arm from the bottom bracket, and would look like this:

[image]

An auto gear puller is also the wrong tool.  You need to unthread, not pull-off.

---

Since you've crossed the threads, its likely that the crank arms are damaged.  It is possible the pedal threads are also damaged.   And the amount of damage will increase the further in you got the pedal axles into the cranks.

You need to back out the pedals, clean all four threads, and inspect closely.  It will take a lot of force to undo this, though not as much as it took to get then in.

Next time something takes that much force on your bike, stop and check.  While some actions do require force, threads are not one of them.

As for recovery, you are probably up for new crank arms, and perhaps pedals.

As an alternative, you might be able to retap the threads using the proper sized (and handed) threadding taps.  However if there's not enough meat left in the crank, another alternative is to helicoil the holes.  For this you'll need a pillar drill (not a hand drill!) and the right helicoils, in both handed-orientations.  This is something a quality LBS can do.